# div under z-index : -1 is not clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi i currently have a page that has multiple layers on it  i have this content-container that i have set  on the back. in my styles.css here is my code

```
#content-container{
/**position**/
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
padding-top: 80px;
padding-left: 80px;
z-index: -1 !important;
/**size**/
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

here is also the `account-container` codes

```
#account-container {
/**position**/
float:right;
margin-top:2px;
margin-right:-60px;

/**size**/
width: 350px;
height: 220px;
border-radius: 5px;

/**color**/
color:black;
background-color: white;
```

}

i set this because i have this `accounts-container` that is when click should be abouve the `content-container`as of now here is what it looks like

[image]

as you can see on the upper right that is the `accounts-container` but what happens is the div `content-container` is not clickable anymore
any ideas?

Comment: can you paste the css for 'account-container'

Comment: is the content-container really use the width of the whole page?

Comment: hi i have just added the codes

Comment: hi @lipp yes it does. is it the wrong way?

Comment: @BourneShady I'd recommend to have the "overlay" just the size its content requires (The visible "white box"). Then you don't need the pointer-events stuff.

Answer (score 5):

If you have any "layer" above (higher z-index) your "accounts-container", this container (the transparent part) must have the CSS property [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) set to none:

```
.whatever {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

This will prevent click events being targeted to the overlay.